# SQL Server Error when building in VS 2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2017

I have a project built in VS2010 and i didn't have any problem building it. Right now, i migrated it in VS2017 and had no problem on the first few weeks even when building a project. After a while, i got this SQL error when trying to rebuild/build the project. Please see the photo attachment below. I tried several workaround but nothing seems to work on me.

Error message:

> Error writing to file: Access is denied
>   
>  . Verify that you have access to that directory.

I am using SQL Server R2 2008 as my database.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got a third error also but i can't post the link since im new here. 

It says: "Error writing to file: Access is denied. Verify that you have access to that directory."

Comment: Screenshots of errors/code are never a good idea...

Comment: @muffi im sorry it's the only thing i can do for now but thanks for your response. I got no errors based on codes, i think this is somehow in sql server/visual studio 2017 application itself.

Comment: What @muffi is trying to tell you is that it's better for you (the OP) to type out the error once, instead of multiple people trying to help each having to type it out